# Object literal alternative in C++

Tags: c++, literals, list-initialization, value-initialization

I'm coming from Javascript like language where I can make functions like this.

```
function tween(obj, tweenParams, time, tweenOptions);
```

This is used like:

```
tween(mySprite, {x: 10, y: 10}, 1, {startDelay: 1, loops: 5});
```

If it's not clear, this lerps mySprite's x and y property to 10 over the course of 1 second, looping 5 times with a 1 second delay. tweenParams can contain any values that the obj might have, and tweenOptions is a fixed struct.

I want to know how terse this can reasonable be in C++, struct and array initializes don't seem flexible enough to express this. My best guess involves calling multiple tween functions one property at a time, something like.

```
TweenOptions opts = {};
opts.startDelay = 1;
opts.loops = 5;
tween(&mySprite.x, 10, 1, opts);
tween(&mySprite.y, 10, 1, opts);
```

I don't know much about C++ advanced features, maybe operator overloading or custom initializes could help me here?

EDIT: To be clear, I don't expect it to exactly match the Javascript example, I just want to know how terse this can reasonably be.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ currently doesn't have anything this clean. C++20 will add *designated initializers* which will make something like this more doable. At this time, you might have to settle for the Builder pattern.

Comment: You wont be able to write `tween(mySprite, {x: 10, y: 10}, 1, {startDelay: 1, loops: 5});` but you will be able to write it as `tween(mySprite, {10, 10}, 1, {1, 5});`.  You can learn how with a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: C++ is not JavaScript. the technique you've shown in your JavaScript code has more cons than pros, and is error prone. just think what would happen if someone had a typo. you will have to "settle" on writing things the C++ style.

Comment: @DavidHaim, lack of designated initializers is a con, not a pro.

Comment: @SergeyA maybe in a statically compiled language, in a dynamic language? no way.

Answer (score 2):

Current versions of C++ do not allow this syntax. However, one of the proposals which according to this [post](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-oulu-june-2016/) was adopted for C++20, will make it possible by using designated initializers (if, of course it will make it there).

The proposal, available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0329r0.pdf), borrows C99 syntax of nominating members when using aggregate initialization in C++ classes. Coupled together with C++11 feature of uniform initializaion, it will allow for very similar syntax to the one you are asking.

For example,

```
struct args {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void foo(args a);
...
foo({.x = 10, .y = 25});
```

Comment: Designated initializers is one of the things I'm looking forward to in C++20. You can do things like this, and it removes the need for quirky named arguments to functions; you can just have the named arguments be part of a struct whose purpose is to be used via a designated initializer.

Comment: @Justin, no argument here. I also think it's a useful feature, and I'd love to see it. In my view, it greatly reduces potential for errors.